# How to kill second gedit?

Tags: linux, process, kill, ps

I executed this command:

```
for run in {1..3}
do
  gedit &
done
```

How can i kill second gedit? 
Because result of this command:
`ps -eo cmd,pid | grep gedit`

is:

```
gedit                        5831
```

So executed this: `kill <pid>` then all of gedits will be closed!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gedit` is probably smart enough to run all its windows in a single process. So when you type `gedit` again, it "connects" to the running process, which then opens a new window.

If you want to close some windows, try `wmctrl`.

`wmctrl -l` lists windows. `wmctrl -c <win_id>` allows you to close a window (as if you clicked the close button).